# Extract frame from VOB(DVD) file

Tags: c#, video, directx, directshow, media

I need to generate thumbnail from video files, i m using IMediaDet to get frame from video, it not working for (*.vob) file DVD, how can i get thumbnail from DVD in C# ..

Comment: You might be able to write your own render filter ... that way you'd have the raw data that you could do what you please with. Dunno if the copy protection mechanisms will stop you doing that though ...

Comment: You need to either use an undecrypted DVD or you need to decrypt your DVD in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear whether or not you are using an unencrypted DVD. For the sake of this answer, I'm going to assume you are.

IMediaDet uses the Sample Grabber filter to perform most of its operations. Unfortunately the Sample Grabber doesn't support the [VIDEOINFOHEADER2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407326(VS.85).aspx) format as indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390180(VS.85).aspx). Some MPEG-2 decoders will only use the VIDEOINFOHEADER2 format, thus preventing the Sample Grabber from connecting, and IMediaDet from working.

I do know that the MPEG-2 decoder from Elecard available [here](http://elecard.com/products/products-pc/consumer/mpeg2-plugin-wmp/) is able to output both VIDEOINFOHEADER and VIDEOINFOHEADER2. It is thus compatible with IMediaDet and should be able to accomplish what you want.