# DirectShow DVD manipulation and capturing

Tags: c#, video, directshow, dvd

I am new to DirectShow.

My intention was to develope a small application (C#) that handles video processing.

The main tasks i need are :

1 - Display video content from a DVD.
2 - Navigate to specific points of time in the video.
3 - Capture specific frames into still images and save them to files.

Sounded easy at first, but after reading thousands of blogs, forums and code samples i can't figure out how this can be done  .

I am pretty sure these tasks have been implemented plenty of times, so if anyone has anything that can help i would be very happy to hear it.

As i am getting desperate on this issue, buying external DLLs or paying for some advice is an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help, but I have a DvdPlayerElement control in my [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/).

You must install an audio codec if you want audio as the built in one with Windows is locked down due to licensing.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can wrap the MSVidWebDVD object, combined with some screen capture techniques [?] see also [Extract frame from VOB(DVD) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476975/extract-frame-from-vobdvd-file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeremiah, I do know WPF MediaKit and tried working with it.

It is pretty cool, but does not allow all of the functionality available in DirectShow.

There are some events missing and the seeking operation does not seem to work for me.

I guess i can dig in the code and figure it out, but the time pressure won't allow it.

If you have an example of an application that accomplishes what i am looking for (display, seek, capture) i would be very happy to take a look.

Thanks again.